# Representation Theorem for Finite Dimensional Algebra over Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

"Every finite dimensional algebra over a field has a faithful matrix representation."

Is the above statement true? If it is, how do I compute such a representation for the geometric algebra $\mathbb{G}^n$?

The question arises here [Equivalence of Left and Right Inverse in Geometric Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280925/equivalence-of-left-and-right-inverse-in-geometric-algebra) where the statement is used to justify equivalence of left and right inverses.

Comment: if your algebra has a unit, the regular representation is faithful.

Comment: Please assume I am very bad at algebra. I mostly know about groups and rings, and almost nothing about representation theory.

Comment: My comment has absolutely nothing to do with representation theory, really...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra with $1$ over a field $k$, let $n$ be it dimension and let $\mathcal B$ be an ordered basis of $A$. For each $a\in A$ there is a linear map $r_a:x\in A\mapsto ax\in A$ given by multiplication on the left by $a$. Let $R(a)$ be the matrix of $r_a$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal B$.

The function $R:a\in A\mapsto R(a)\in M_n(k)$ is a faithful matrix representation of $A$.

Comment: Why must it be faithful? Could there be two vectors that both act as identity?

Comment: Oh then just multiply them together to show they are equal

Comment: Hm? I don't know what you mean by 'multiply them together"... In any case: the function $R$ is injective simply because when $a$ and $b$ are different elements of $a$ the values $r_a(1)$ and $r_b(1)$ are different.

Comment: "Let $R(a)$ be the matrix of $r_a$" already presupposes that there exists a matrix representation.

Comment: @user48672, huh? No: I **defined** a linear map $r_a$ and I am taking the matrix of that linear map with respecto a fixed ordered basis.

Answer (score 0):

This result is true if you suppose that the algebra is simple.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem

Comment: And also if you don't suppose that.