# Show that $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$ maps identity to identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings

Here is the function I am speaking about:

Recall that the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ has basis $\{1 ,\sqrt 3\}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}.$ Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}] \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ be the subring $\{ a_{1} + a_{2}\sqrt{3}| a_{1},a_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$

Show that the function $$\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{Q}), \phi (a_{1} + a_{2}\sqrt{3}) =  \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & 3a_{2} \\
a_{2} & a_{1} 
\end{pmatrix} $$ is an injective ring homomorphism.

**My question is:**

I have no problem in showing the following:

1- Showing that it is injective.

2- Showing that it preserves addition.

3- Showing that it preserves multiplication.

But I have a problem in

4- Showing that it maps the identity element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ to the identity element of $M_{2}(\mathbb{Q}).$

I know the identity element of $M_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$ which is $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} $$ but it is not clear for me what is the identity element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}),$ could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: The identity is obviously $1$. This is represented by $1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot \sqrt{3}$ (i.e. $a_1=1, a_2=0$).

Comment: It is realty not that difficult to tell which element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$ is mapped to that matrix. You already have the formula for $\phi$.

Comment: @Crostul is not it the additive identity not the multiplicative identity ? in proving the ring homomorphism? So the additive identity in this ring is 1?

Comment: The additive identity is obviously $0$...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3844191/589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ contains $\Bbb{Q}$ as a subring. Hence the identity (additive or multiplicative) of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is that of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: So clearly the given map maps $0$ to $0$?

Comment: @Confusion Yes.

Comment: @Confusion No, clearly the given map maps $0$ (which is the additive identity of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$) to $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ (which is the additive identity of $M_2(\Bbb Q)$).

Comment: @Confusion Are you asking me whether something is clear to you?

Comment: No never @Servaes mind I meant what Arthur wrote